# how to run method in view controller without touching button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making tic Tac Toe

and  I want to make a method that checks the winner of my Game without touch a button

so i tried to make this

```
-(void)printSomeThing{

    NSLog(@"Checking ... We Are Playing");
}
```

to try what if it runs or not

but it didn't

so how to run this method and print out that words

Answer (score 1):

Some ways I can see you making this method work without touching a button:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[self printSomeThing];
}
```

**OR**

Whenever your function is called to realize that the game is over you tell it there to call the function the same way i did in the viewDidLoad, by using:

```
   [self printSomeThing];
```

Hope this helps any

Comment: your viewDidLoad should be in your .m file already within the viewController

Comment: I know that of course it is in the .m file

Comment: Do you mean to  type this


- (void)viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok iknow that it will run if i open that file immediately  only in the first time 

but the problem is that i want to run it every loop 
i am making Tic Tac Toe 
so every turn i should Check  that

Comment: So why not make an action for say like an "invisible button" that hides behind each tic tac toe spot. and make to where the user clicks on it, it creates an action seeing whether or not there is three in a row or not. I guess my next question is, how are you making it add the tic tac toe without there being an action called using a button? Can you please edit your post and possibly put some of your code on there so i can understand your situation more clearly.